# Can I treat the USB controller in the ATMEGA8U2 as seperate from the rest of the microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, avr, atmega

I'm working on a project that runs on a battery, but can be connected to a computer for a serial connection/charging. In the documentation it lists an example of a bus powered USB controller with separately powered rest of chip, so I was wondering if it would be okay to leave UVCC floating while no USB cable is attached.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. There is no need to be rude, actually it reduces the chance for answers. The bot is triggered by human community members, who flagged this question most probably as unclear...

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 2.1 of the [complete data sheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc7799.pdf) shows the block diagram. It reveals that UVCC and UCAP are input and output, respectively, of the on-chip 3.3V regulator. It looks like you need to operate it for correct function of the USB controller, even if you have no USB communication.

Chapter 20.3 lists several powering options. What you want is a **self powered device**.

Connect UVCC to the separate power supply, but do not connect it to VBUS of the USB connector. Please be aware that there are at least two alternatives, depending on your I/O voltage requirements.

This way the USB controller receives power, but it is happy without any USB cable.

To reduce the power consumption, read about the power modes of the USB controller in chapter 20.5.

*Note: Chapter 20.3.3 has additional design guidelines. And I'm sure there are application notes on the matter, too.*

---

### Warning

As RohatKılıç comments and answers, the data sheet is apparently wrong in chapter 20.3. Chapter 1 shows the pin configurations, which do not include VBUS. Unfortunately, there is no corrected data sheet nor errata sheet.

So connect UVCC of the MCU to VBUS of the USB connector and power the MCU separately. UVCC is actually not "floating" as it has a not-so-high input impedance (indication: the supply current for an enabled regulator).

However, I leave this answer as is to show how to tackle such questions. Feel free to add sources and facts that show the correct wiring.

Comment: `What you want is a self powered device. ... Connect UVCC to the separate power supply, but do not connect it to VBUS of the USB connector.` the datasheet has a mistake/error here. The devices in the series have no such pin as "VBUS". This has been reported to Atmel and Microchip several times. They admitted that they did a mistake (probably copied from another chip's datasheet) but apparently haven't fixed it yet.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks for notifying! What is the correct wiring? We should add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ... so i was wondering if it would be okay to leave the UVCC floating while no USB cable is attached.

Yes. UVCC is the supply input for the USB module. It has its own regulator inside which requires an external output cap to be connected across UCAP and GND.

In the bus-powered configuration the entire chip is supplied from USB so it needs to be connected to the USB to run fully.

What you can take as a reference is the Figure 20-5 (self-powered configuration) of the datasheet **but the datasheet has a mistake here**: The chip has no such pin as VBUS, also the UVCC pin is supplied constantly. This is reported to Atmel/Microchip several times. Apparently, no action is taken.

Anyway...

You can take the UVCC input from USB 5V directly (through an external filter if needed), and supply the rest of the circuit (VCC and, if required, AVCC) with an independent supply (e.g. on-board regulator).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feBksV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**NOTE:** Decoupling caps and supply filters are not shown.